# Converting a date a string to java.sql.Date format

Tags: java, sql, date, sqldatetime

I'm having an issue while trying to insert a date into an SQL server using Java:

```
//final String input = "20120823151034";
final String input = "06282013143533";

final DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMddyyyyHHmmss");
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(df.parse(input));
//c.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 1);
String s=df.format(c.getTime());
java.util.Date parsedUtilDate = df.parse(s);  
java.sql.Date sqltDate= new java.sql.Date(parsedUtilDate.getTime());  
System.out.println(sqltDate);
```

Here, I'm expecting the complete string being output as the year, month, day, hour, minutes, and seconds to be inserted into SQL server, but I'm only getting the year, month, and the date. What should I do to insert the date and the time into the database?

Comment: why are you converting string->calendar->string->date->....whats the point? also does c.setTime(df.parse(input)); work after making it final?

Comment: here the requirement is i will be given a date with 06282013143533 i have to insert it into sqlserver db so iam trying to convert the date given to sql server compatible!!

Answer (score 4):

check your DATA type in database either it should be `Timestamp` or `Datetime`for this purpose you can use database function `NOW()` for current date and time.and convert your date into timestamp

```
  Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(new Date().getTime());
```

and insert this `timestamp` into database

Comment: could you please tell me how to get that,its not for current date and time it should be applicable to previous dates also

Comment: convert your date string to date then convert it to date then timestamp insert it.

Answer (score 1):

`java.sql.Date` can be used to store only the year, month and day of the month. It can't be used to store the time of the day.

In order to store time, you would have to use `Timestamp`. In your above code, replace

```
java.sql.Date sqltDate= new java.sql.Date(parsedUtilDate.getTime());
```

by

```
java.sql.Timestamp timestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(parsedUtilDate.getTime());
```

The above changes will make things work fine.